# Replace a subset pandas dataframe with rows and columns via a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I would like to use a numpy array to replace a subset dataframe from a pandas dataframe.

For example:
a pandas dataframe `df`.

```
df_subset = df.loc[[1,3,5,7,9], ["A", "B", "C"]]
```

Here, the subset dataframe has a dimension of `(5, 3)`:

And below is the numpy array example with the same shape as the subset dataframe I would like to replace to:

```
replace_value = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 4], [1, 6, 8], [1, 3, 6], [8, 0, 1]])
```

Is there any approach similar to:

```
df_subset.values = replace_value
```

What I hope is that the value I replaced will directly change the original values in `df`. Which means that if I subset `df` with the same indice and columns again, I will get the exact values as the numpy array I assigned as `replace_value` above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try via `loc` accessor:

```
df.loc[[1,3,5,7,9], ["A", "B", "C"]]=replace_value
#just like you grabbed values you can also assign that back like that
```

sample data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(25,3),columns=["A", "B", "C"])
replace_value = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 4], [1, 6, 8], [1, 3, 6], [8, 0, 1]])
df.loc[[1,3,5,7,9], ["A", "B", "C"]]=replace_value
```

Comment: Yes! This worked! Thank you! I was stuck in replacing values need to use `.loc[ ].values`. :P